# C pointers as struct members, allocation, initialization

Tags: c, pointers, structure, dynamic-allocation

I'm working on an algebra application, here's the code

```
struct quotient
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

struct term
{
    struct quotient coefficient;
    char varname;
    struct quotient power;
};

struct function
{
    struct term* terms;
    char* operators;
    struct quotient coefficient;
    struct quotient power;
};

//Constructor Functions
struct quotient NewQuotient()
{
    struct quotient temp;
    printf("Enter the numerator\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp.numerator);
    printf("Enter the denominator\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp.denominator);
    return temp;
}

char NewVarname()
{
    char temp;
    printf("Enter the variable letter: \n");
    scanf("%c", &temp);
    return temp;
}

struct term NewTerm()
{
    //broken, won't let you enter a variable name, sets it to x by default until that's     resolved
    struct term temp;
    printf("Enter the coefficient: ");
    temp.coefficient = NewQuotient();
    printf("Enter the variable name: \n");
    temp.varname = NewVarname();
    temp.varname = 'x';
    printf("Enter the power: ");
    temp.power = NewQuotient();
    return temp;
}

void NewFunction(struct function* func, int size)
{
    //so far so good
    unsigned i;
    func->terms = (struct term*)calloc(size, sizeof(struct term));
    //loop to initialize each term
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        func->terms[i] = NewTerm();
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    struct function fofx;
    NewFunction(&fofx, 2);
    DisplayFunction(&fofx, 2);
    DeleteFunction(&fofx);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

> Enter the numerator:
>       1
>   Enter the denominator:
>       2
>   Enter the numerator:
>       3
>   Enter the denominator:
>       4
>   ....

etc, until the end of the loop.

Half of the statements in NewTerm don't seem to be executing at all, but the program seems to successfully allocate and initialize a new function. Any help is very much appreciated, I am very confused about this. I didn't include the display and delete function, they work fine, but if they'd be helpful I can add them on here.

Comment: You didn't post the code for NewQuotient. You should post the entire relevant code.

Comment: Sorry about that, thought I had it in there, it's added now.

Comment: The code for struct term is missing. Can you post all the relevant code so I can compile/try it.

Comment: I Added the structures and the main function, I think that's everything.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving the right size to calloc, that should be `sizeof (struct term)` rather than `sizeof (int)`.
This might be the problem, depending on the actual size of `struct term` and what value you have for `size`.

Regarding `NewTerm` not being called, that's probably because you're not calling it.

Comment: That was part of it, that was causing the core dump. The scanf statements are still behaving badly though.

Comment: You're going to have to do better than "behaving badly" or "not working correctly" to get a useful answer about that

Comment: yes indeed, it was recompiled and run with the same input and produced the same output.

Comment: So when you run it, it doesn't even output "Enter the coefficient"? What is your main function ?

Answer (score 1):

When using `scanf`, you generally want to get the Return key as well as the number.

You have:

```
scanf("%d", &temp.numerator);
```

You really want:

```
scanf("%d\n", &temp.numerator);
```

Comment: When I run this myself, I find that `scanf("\n%d", %temp.numerator);` works, while putting the `\n` at the end doesn't.

Comment: Whichever way you do it, just be sure you capture ALL the characters the user types in.  [Return] isn't captured by %d, but needs to captured somewhere/somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use validation to make sure only numbers are entered or you'll get wacky results.